# How would you explain Nothing[] weirdness?

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment, index

I would like to use `Nothing[]` to make some elements of a list invisible. (The intended use is to remove a few unwanted points from a `ListPlot`.) But sometimes it seems that the operation fails:

```
x = {a, b, c, d, e} (* Create a list *)
(*{a, b, c, d, e}*)

x[[3]] = Nothing (* Remove an element *)
(*Nothing*)

x
(*{a, b, d, e} (* Third element successfully removed. *)*)

x[[3]]
(*d   (* The third element is now 'd' instead of 'c' *)*)

x[[1]] = Nothing (* Remove the first element *)
(*Nothing*)

x
(*{b, d, e} (* The first element removed successfully. *)*)

x[[3]] = Nothing (* Remove the third element *)
(*Nothing*)

x
(*{b, d, e} (* List is unchanged! *)*)

x[[3]]
(*e*)
```

Of course, assigning `Nothing[]` does not actually 'delete' anything.

```
Definition[x]
(*x = {Nothing, b, Nothing, d, e}*)
```

The documentation says "`Nothing[]` is removed during the standard evaluation process." This then makes me believe that assigning `Nothing[]` does not involve the standard evaluation process.

This is rather annoying, because now the indexes used by standard evaluation and the `Nothing[]` assignment do not match.

```
Position[x, d]
(*{{2}} (* Yes, the element 'd' is in the list *)*)

x[[Position[x, d] // First]] = Nothing[] (* Try to remove element 'd' *)
(*Nothing*)

x
(*{d, e} (* The element 'd' was not removed! *)*)

x[[1]] = z; x
(*{z, d, e} (* This is just weird *)*)
```

I guess I'm posting this more as a warning than as a question. If there are suggestions on how to do it differently, or if I'd missed something in the documentation that explains this behaviour I'd be most interested.

My next step would be to collect the indices of the elements I want to disappear and assign `Nothing[]` to them in a singe step, rather than trying to remove them piecemeal.

Comment: If you want to instantly remove something use e.g. **Delete** or **Drop**.

Comment: The question could be rephrased from "a warning about this weirdness" to "why is this behaving weirdly?"

Comment: `x[[1]] = Nothing` changes the first element of `x` to be `Nothing`. It does not re-evaluate *the entire* contents of `x` and then re-assign the result to `x`.

Comment: The person who voted to reopen: it's better to explain *why* it should be reopened. If you make that clear, others will vote too.

Comment: @Niel You don't have to use `Nothing[]`. In fact I find that usage strange. `Nothing` is the usual way. `Nothing[x]` something one would normally create with `Apply` or by `Replace`ing a head (`Missing` -> `Nothing`)

Comment: @Szabolcs I chose to write `Nothing[]` instead of `Nothing` to make it clear that I meant the Mathematica function and not the common word 'nothing'. It also matches the way `Sequence[]' is used for the same purpose.

Comment: `Nothing` is not a function. It is a symbol. `Sequence` is very different: you *must* use `Sequence[]`. It has to be used as a function. If you are using `Nothing` and not `Nothing[]` in your code, then please do not keep referring to `Nothing[]`—they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the best way to understand this behavior is with this example,

```
In[99]:= x = {a, b, c, d, e};

In[101]:= Length@x

Out[101]= 5

In[102]:= x[[3]] = Nothing;

In[103]:= Length[x]

Out[103]= 4

In[104]:= Block[{Nothing}, Length[x]]

Out[104]= 5
```

When you say `x[[3]] = Nothing`, you are **not** deleting an element from `x`. `x` is still a 5-element list.  But `x` is now something that will **evaluate** to a 4-element list.

`Nothing` has evaluation rules such that it becomes `Sequence[]` when inside a `List`.  So when you use `x` it has to re-evaluate every time,

```
In[107]:= TracePrint[x, _List]

During evaluation of In[107]:=  {a,b,Nothing,d,e}

During evaluation of In[107]:=  {a,b,d,e}

Out[107]= {a, b, d, e}
```

In general I would avoid `Part` modification like this, where you create an expression that isn't finished evaluating.

As mentioned in the comments, to delete a part of a list use [`Delete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html). If you want to use `Nothing` it is necessary to add another evaluation step, like

```
x[[3]] = Nothing;
x = x
```

or

```
x = ReplacePart[x, 3 -> Nothing]
```

I find `Nothing` to be very useful.  Often I'm compiling a list and I do

```
elem1 = If[condition1, val1, Nothing];
elem2 = If[condition2, val2, Nothing];
list = {elem1, elem2}
```

I find it easier to use than `Sequence @@ {}` in these cases.